# Modeling Organic Architecture

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model some organic architecture with a facade inspired by the bloomhouse in texas. Any explanation on how you would model a draping facade like the image attached would be very helpful as I have no clue where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Vast majority of modelling tools and techniques I can think of can be used here. There is no single right answer here. These are complex forms and you will need everything you got for modelling this.

I would like to direct your attention to understanding what you wish to model exactly. Is it something exact from a reference? Is it something that you want to create that only has a mood like your reference? It's important to get/imagine an idea of what it is in 3d space that you want to model. If you are creating something of this mood, study the shapes and forms that are characteristic to the reference and imagine them in space(I did not spend much time on that in the example).

If it needed to be something exact that already exists in real world, you would need a lot of reference photographs. It might even make sense to just scan the thing if possible, or use photographs for [photogrammetric reconstruction](https://alicevision.org/) and then just do retopology.

If it's something you want to create, that's also a very tricky task, because modelling this is not easy and it will be time consuming so it will take loads of time to try different versions and variations. Some sketching by hand or by other means(grease pencil would be perfect for this because you can sketch in 3d) might be a very good idea to save time.

You could use various simulations or geometry nodes, but that makes sense only if you need a lot of structures in this style, because initial setup will be very complex and time consuming, likely even requiring more effort than to do this "by hand" once.

It might be very useful to approach this by defining whatever you can in 3d space first. I would probably start with simple curve lines as you can probably see where they are from the reference or you can imagine where you want them when creating it from scratch and you don't need to spend time on the geometry, but simply imagine it instead(also good for sketching, you could use grease pencil for creating them, I am just not used to using it):

[image]

Then you can convert the curves to meshes, join them to a single object and start modelling the geometry between them. It would make sense to keep the geometry amount as low as possible at this stage, because the lower it is, the less vertices there are for you to move and the amount of vertices that you need to move may quickly become a nightmare.

[image]

Then you can define forms further. Maybe use some sculpting. Then you could use solidify and subdivision surface modifiers, apply them and you would have a mesh that you could sculpt further(subdivided more than what I have, obviously):

[image]

This is just one vague suggestion of some sort of a workflow, but you could do a lot of stuff in-between those steps I describe and after. Or you could chose a totally different technique, this is just something I would do.